# AseConnection InfoMessage returning print statement as an error message

Tags: c#, t-sql, sap-ase

I am working in Sybase ASE 15.7 and I am trying to return messages from a T-SQL as shown below. I'm using the AseConnection.InfoMessage event handler to capture messages from the database. It is working fine but it is also returning the print statement as an AseError message. Why is this happening and how can I correct it?

Console Output:

> Log: 12522 rows in SomeTable
>
> AseError Log: 12522 rows in SomeTable

```
string sql= @"set nocount on
              declare @rowcount    int                            
              select  @rowcount = count(*) from SomeTable
              print   'Log: %1! rows in SomeTable', @rowcount";

using (var conn = GetOpenConnection(connectionString))
{
   conn.InfoMessage += (s,e) =>
   {
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
      foreach (var error in e.Errors)
         Console.WriteLine(error.ToString())
   };
   using (var command = new AseCommand(sql, conn))
   {
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Comment: I´ve used a normal System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand to do something similar, there the prints were also stored in e.Errors, the e.Message was the same, all "errors" joined by a linebreak. I would say, it´s just a matter of designation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a really bizarre design decision by the authors of the driver. All messages, errors and info, share a data structure that describes the message as an `AseError`.

I work on an open source project that produces a [.NET Core version](https://github.com/DataAction/AdoNetCore.AseClient) of the `AseClient`. One of the goals of that project is to be a drop-in replacement for the driver from SAP/Sybase - and for that reason we have replicated the above design decision - as weird as it is.

A severity `>10` is considered an error. Otherwise it is considered informational. If it helps you make sense of it, here is our code for interpreting the server messages: [MessageTokenHandler.cs](https://github.com/DataAction/AdoNetCore.AseClient/blob/master/src/AdoNetCore.AseClient/Internal/Handler/MessageTokenHandler.cs)